# How to display the font awesome icon inside the input field when the field is empty?

Tags: html, css, jquery-validate

I have to display the font awesome icon inside the input field when the field is empty.

I am using jquery validation. When I clicked on the submit button then

I am getting the output. I have to display the icon with equal space from the top, bottom, right side in all the input field if the field is small or big.

Would you help me out with this?

[image]

```js
$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    firstname: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    middlename: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },

    lastname: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
    },

    phone: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      number: true
    }

  },

  messages: {
    email: {
      required: "This field is required.",
      email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
}

form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-control.error {
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}

input.form-control.error+ :after {
  content: "\f06a";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32%;
  right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" name="form" id="form" method="post">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>firstname</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Middlename</label>
          <input type="text" name="middlename" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Lastname</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Phone</label>
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems like this is mostly a CSS issue.  What have you tried?  Did you adjust positioning values in the CSS?  Instead of percentages, did you consider pixels?

Comment: @Sparky, I tried position: absolute. top and bottom. You can check in my css.  it's working but not working with all the input field.

Comment: I have to display the validation error icon inside input field

Comment: Again, did you try using **pixel values instead of percentages**?  Not working with all input fields?  Your demo shows the exact same thing on all input fields.

Comment: @Sparky, You edited your first comment that I haven't checked. I haven't tried using the pixel value. Let me check this also

Comment: Your code has been do what you want.

Comment: @Sparky, Yes, Pixels is working insted of percentages.

Comment: @Sparky, I checked again it's working but if my label is big text then I am getting an issue. I mean label text is more then 100 character then not displaying proper